# Edit and Reopen: Under the hood of review queues

Tags: support, review, re-open

I was reviewing [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005387/math-research-problem-sources) in the Reopen review queue, prompted by some editing done by the OP.

Given the clarifications in the body of the Question, I was tempted to edit the Title as well, for consistency, since it is now clear that research level problems are not really of interest.

Then I got to thinking about the mechanics of the Reopen review queue, which tries to highlight the edits that have instigated the review.

My worry was that my comparatively trivial edit might mask the prior edit of the OP.

Does anyone know if that would happen?  I was unable to find information one way or the other among the Meta posts here on review queues, though there are some tangentially related topics.

Comment: I gave the post an edit and a reopen vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your edit will not mask the earlier one. A [scientific experiment by hichris123](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2617901#2617901) showed that the reopen queue displays the difference between the present version and *the one that was closed*. He made a small edit to a closed post:

[image: edit]

and observed that the Revision tab of Reopen queue showed all  edits since the closure:

[image: review]